# Using a custom PHP.INI for a single site. Windows 2003, 64bit, IIS7.5, PHP 5.3.6

Tags: php, iis-7.5, windows-server-2003

I have a single PHP script on a single site that requires me to set the upload size maximum fairly high. I would prefer not to do this globally.

According to the PHP docs, I can not set the values for some variable such as `post_max_size` , `max_file_uploads` or `upload_max_filesize` using `ini_set`. I've seen a number of solutions here running PHP on a UNIX box or on Windows running Apache, but none that are clear to me using IIS.

My understanding is that there is a way for me to have a custom php.ini file to override specific php.ini value.

Ideally, I would love to have a php.ini file in the folder with that one script that looks something like this:

```
[PHP]
post_max_size = 200M
max_file_uploads = 5
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

How can I accomplish this without setting the values globally on my server?

Comment: Not sure about IIS, but on an Apache server, you can specify settings in a .htaccess file. Example:

`php_value upload_max_filesize 32M`

Comment: @Brad ; good question: How do I determine that?

Comment: @Brad I have CGI installed and in the root of IIS, I have "FastCGI Settings" panel.

Comment: @HumanBacon, How did you set up PHP?  When you installed PHP, you would have set it up one way or the other.  The reason I ask, is if I remember correctly, you can specify a different command line to run scripts for different sites.  If that is the case, you can specify the different INI file on the command line.  `phpinfo()` may tell you, but if I remember correctly, it just says CGI/FastCGI, rather than one or the other.  It's been awhile since I've used IIS... I don't completely remember.

Comment: @HumanBacon, Hmmm, sorry, I don't know how to do this with FastCGI.  I'm sure it's possible though.  Hopefully someone else knows the answer.  You might consider moving this question over to ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a seperate ini file for each website using the PHPRC environment variable as stated here http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php.

And here is an article on how to set it for IIS 6 and 7.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/745/enable-per-site-php-configuration-on-iis-60-and-iis-7-and-above/

Hope this helps